# Android studio, solve problem with missing local.properties file after cloning git repo

Tags: android, git

I want to work on my project on several devices, hence I'm using git clone. However, after doing so I always get an error with incorrect sdk.dir path (missing local.properties). As far as I know adding it manually is dangerous, so my question is how can I solve this conveniently, without any issues?

Comment: Why adding it manually would be dangerous? local.properties is there to be only locally (on your computer), feel free to add it there

Comment: local.properties is just a file contains the SDK and NDK location, you can add it manually